# JUnit, how can i test if a LocalDate is not valid?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I'm doing some testing for a university project.

I wanted to test a method *verifyCorrectDates(LocalDate firstDate, LocalDate lastDate)*.

In general, i think we could see these possible scenarios:

- a LocalDate is null
- a LocalDate is not valid (for example, 2023-40-40)
- a LocalDate is valid

Since i have two LocalDates as input, there should be 9 test to comprehend every situation.

Thing is: i don't know how can i test this method using a 'non valid date'.
If i use LocalDate.of(2023,40,40) it simply gives me an error, of course. I'm starting to think it's simply not possible to insert a non valid LocalDate.

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, one would assume the factory method for `LocalDate` throws an exception in that case. But the function you want to test seems to take _two_ dates. What are the behaviours of that function? That is, what is it supposed to do? You should be testing those things.

Comment: Thing is, it seems like a not possible scenario, because i cant call the method by passing to it _a non valid date._ The error would be on a higher level. Think about this:

LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2024-40-40);
LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.of(2024-60-60);

verifyCorrectDates(date, date2);

This would simply not compile, since the LocalDate.of(...) would give me error. So i cannot test it in my method.

Comment: Oh yeah, i get it. Since my method does not accept a String, but a LocalDate, i shouldn't test this. If my method accepted two Strings that would be the case i'm imagining.

Answer (score 3):

You should not create invalid LocalDate instances, as those will throw exceptions, so its not practical in case of testing your function. You can still come up with valid test scenerios, like check correctness of function call if its called when:

1. both dates are null
2. first date is null, the second date is valid.
3. first date is valid, the second date is null.
4. both dates are valid, and the first date is after the second date.
5. both dates are valid, and the first date is before the second date
6. dates are valid, and the first date is the same as the second date.